# Altimeter app that records

Tags: iphone, applications, jailbreak

I'm looking for a gps based altimeter app that records elevation to the phone. I will be out of cell range so it needs to store data on the phone.  Do you know of one?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Gaia GPS](http://www.gaiagps.com/) app. It works offline and has a free version so you can do your test before buying.

Answer (score 1):

I use Altimeter GPS for iPhone and it works very well for me! Try it!

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/altimeter-gps-elevation-compass/id572227849?l=it&ls=1&mt=8